# Programming tool companion, Windows 8 Release Preview and VS 2012 RC

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Sorry for this out out topic question, but really need this information. I am using Windows 8 Release Preview and I want to install VS 2012 express, but my recent download is not compatible with this version of windows, can I use VS 2012 RC to be install on my computer? Or do you have suggestion that work for my version of windows?

Comment: Windows 8 became publicly available two days ago.  Thirty nine bucks solve your problem.

Comment: I know but I curious why some folks can do it this version of windows by changing framework version registry

Comment: I downloaded Windows 8 RC and Visual Studio 2012 Express worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you install [Windows 8 evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx) instead? It works for 90 days.